# magento 1.8 to set multi stores with single website, is it need to create multiple website

Tags: magento-1.8, php, multistore

I am creating multi store in single website in one magento 1.8 installation. I gone through with many tutorials and documents for this. I have doubt that is it necessary to create multiple website also.??

http://www.inventcommerce.com/blogs/90-setting-up-multi-storefronts-on-magento

I want to do it in single main website. Is it possible.? If I did it with multi website and single store for each and all are website are belongs to main website is it similler to my requirement???

Help me

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use e.g. three stores under one website or create three separate websites with one store each depends on your business requirements.

An example of a requirement which would require 1:1 website:store relationship is if you wanted your price scope to be specific to each store:

[image: Screenshot of price scope selection]

Ultimately, it's up to you to determine.